# In what way a User url can be created with GWT

Tags: gwt

I have this web app which is a directory of users from a database, the web app works just fine with all the widgets/components that allow user search and show results in gwt panels. However I am thinking to add a way a User can have a user like:

mygwtapp.com/user123

And gwt app will show the appropriate view for the user?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this in GWT is using the history mechanism:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html

Basically, instead of:

- mygwtapp.com/user123

You can do something like this:

- mygwtapp.com/gwtapp.html#user123

Once you understand the basics, you can use activities and places (a simple framework on top of gwt's history api). But this is a bit more complicated and probably unnecessary for your needs.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

Comment: Also, its important that the user address will have a format like: mygwtapp.com/user123